# django-admin.py: command not found

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have django-admin.py in usr/local/bin and I have tried all the help given on the web to make a symbolic link but it still says django-admin.py: command not found.

I am trying to start of my first project in django :- django-admin.py startproject mysite.

No matter what I do I just keep on getting  django-admin.py: command not found.

I am using ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks

Comment: What does your `PATH` look like? Try typing `echo $PATH` at the prompt.

Comment: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: And you're sure that `django-admin.py` is, in fact, in `/usr/local/bin`? What does `which django-admin.py` return?

Comment: Can you check if the script is executable?

Comment: it returns nothing.the prompt appears again. I tried opening django-admin.py but it wont. it says - The Link "django-admin.py" is Broken. Move it to Trash?

Comment: I tried opening django-admin.py but it wont. it says - The Link "django-admin.py" is Broken. Move it to Trash?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py` ?

Answer (score 4):

just type

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to remove it and install Django again.

Or use virtualenv http://www.mahdiyusuf.com/post/5282169518/beginners-guide-easy-install-pip-and-virtualenv-1

Comment: I went removed Django and installed pip and virtualenv. I tried django-admin.py startproject mysite - but the problem still remains.

Comment: How do I make use of what I just did?

Comment: You need to create virtualenv like "virtualenv --no-site-packages /path/to/your/env" and then activate it with "source /path/to/your/env/bin/activate". That will change temporary your path, and you can check you're using it because the prompt also changed.

Then, try to install Django again (pip install django) and check if that works.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same Problem. the `django-admin.py` for me was in this Path `~/.local/bin`.
this because i run `pip instal --user django`